# How can i display my recyclerview on my screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a horizontal RecyclerView that is inside a vertical RecyclerView
My App is running smoothly but RecyclerView doesn't show up on HomeFragment

**Here is my HomeFragment:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="420dp"
                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_tommyteo_foreground"
                    android:gravity="bottom">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvtommy"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/metropolis_bold"
                            android:text="Tommy Hilfiger"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="35sp" />
                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/button"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/metropolis_bold"
                            android:paddingStart="40dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="40dp"
                            android:text="CHECK" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/horizontalRV"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="133dp"
                            android:scrollbars="horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Here is my HomeFragment.java**

```
package com.nguyentrantienhiep;

import android.os.Bundle;


import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.nguyentrantienhiep.home.Home;
import com.nguyentrantienhiep.home.HomeAdapter;
import com.nguyentrantienhiep.product.Product;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link HomeFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private RecyclerView rvHome;
    private View view;
    private HomeActivity homeActivity;

    public HomeFragment() {

        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
        homeActivity = (HomeActivity) getActivity();

        rvHome = view.findViewById(R.id.horizontalRV);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new        LinearLayoutManager(homeActivity,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false);
        rvHome.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        HomeAdapter homeAdapter = new HomeAdapter(getListProduct());
        rvHome.setAdapter(homeAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    private List<Home> getListProduct() {
        List<Home> listHome = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Product> listProduct = new ArrayList<>();
        listProduct.add(new Product(R.mipmap.ic_product,"TAO"));
        listProduct.add(new Product(R.mipmap.ic_product,"TAO1"));
        listProduct.add(new Product(R.mipmap.ic_product,"TAO2"));
        listProduct.add(new Product(R.mipmap.ic_product,"TAO3"));
        listProduct.add(new Product(R.mipmap.ic_product,"TAO4"));

        listHome.add(new Home("NEW",listProduct));
        listHome.add(new Home("Best Selling",listProduct));
        listHome.add(new Home("Most Favorites",listProduct));

        return listHome;
    }


}
```

**Here is my Product and ProductAdapter**

```
package com.nguyentrantienhiep.product;

 public class Product {
    private int resourceId;
    private String title;

    public Product(int resourceId, String title) {
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getResourceId() {
        return resourceId;
    }

    public void setResourceId(int resourceId) {
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

```
package com.nguyentrantienhiep.product;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.nguyentrantienhiep.R;

import java.util.List;

public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder>{

    private List<Product> mProducts;

    public void setData(List<Product> list){
        this.mProducts=list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_item,parent,false);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Product product = mProducts.get(position);
        if (product == null){
            return;
        }
        holder.imgProduct.setImageResource(product.getResourceId());
        holder.brands.setText(product.getTitle());
        holder.prdname.setText(product.getTitle());
        holder.price.setText(product.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(mProducts != null) {
            return mProducts.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private ImageView imgProduct;
        private TextView brands;
        private TextView prdname;
        private TextView price;

        public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgProduct = imgProduct.findViewById(R.id.title_image);
            brands = brands.findViewById(R.id.tvbrand);
            prdname = prdname.findViewById(R.id.tvprdname);
            price = price.findViewById(R.id.tvprice);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my Home and HomeAdapter**

```
package com.nguyentrantienhiep.home;

import com.nguyentrantienhiep.product.Product;

import java.util.List;

public class Home {
    private String nameCategory;
    private List<Product> products;

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }



    public Home(String nameCategory, List<Product> products) {
        this.nameCategory = nameCategory;
        this.products = products;
    }

    public String getNameCategory() {
        return nameCategory;
    }

    public void setNameCategory(String nameCategory) {
        this.nameCategory = nameCategory;
    }
}
```

```
package com.nguyentrantienhiep.home;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.nguyentrantienhiep.R;
import com.nguyentrantienhiep.product.ProductAdapter;

import java.util.List;

public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder>{

    private List<Home> mListHome;

    public HomeAdapter(List<Home> list) {
        this.mListHome = mListHome;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HomeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_home,parent,false);
        return new HomeViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HomeViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Home tao = mListHome.get(position);
        if(tao == null){
            return;
        }
        holder.tvCatName.setText(tao.getNameCategory());

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager((Context) mListHome, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false);
        holder.rvProduct.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        ProductAdapter productAdapter = new ProductAdapter();
        productAdapter.setData(tao.getProducts());
        holder.rvProduct.setAdapter(productAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(mListHome!=null){
            return mListHome.size();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public class HomeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView tvCatName;
        private RecyclerView rvProduct;

        public HomeViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvCatName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvnew);
            rvProduct = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvProduct);
        }
    }
}
```

**This one is category**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvnew"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/metropolis_bold"
            android:text="New"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvnew"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/metropolis_bold"
            android:text="You never seen before"
            android:textColor="@color/textAd"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/metropolis_bold"
            android:text="View all"
            android:textColor="@color/textAd"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvProduct"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="133dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**This one is product**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="177dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/title_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="177dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_product"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/product_bg"
                android:text="12%"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rtbProductRating"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:rating="4.5"
            android:isIndicator="false"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvbrand"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RARE vibes"
            android:textColor="@color/textAd"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvprdname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/mainText"
            android:text="Maroon &amp; Beige"
            android:fontFamily="@font/metropolis_regular"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvprice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="$39"
            android:textColor="@color/primary"
            android:fontFamily="@font/metropolis_regular"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

[It should be right below the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYgfO.png)

[But it doesn't show right there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da5L3.png)

Comment: Why do u have `android:layout_height="0dp"` in `LinearLayout` in Home Fragment .

Comment: thank you, i fixed that, but it still didn't show

Comment: missing for `notifyDataSetChanged` ?

Comment: can you point out where am i missing for **notifyDataSetChanged**?